# Regular expression to match directory paths using joi + express

Tags: javascript, regex, joi

I am trying to find regexp to match directory path using joi and express

My requirement is this

```
test/upload- Valid
test/upload/123/123/123/ - valid (These can be a nested folder)
```

I have tried many ways using joi with lot of regex but it is still failing. I am attaching the screenshot also with my test data and regex which is this

```
 /^test?([a-z0-9A-Z ]{1,}\/)+/ //this is defined as pattern 1
```

I will really appreciate it if someone can help me on this. I have been staring at this for long time now

this is my joi string

`ilepath: Joi.string().regex(pattern1).required(),`

[image]

Comment: Is the problem with the regex itself that is does not fully match those 4 examples or with joi?

Comment: @Thefourthbird regex seems to be fine...I have attached the screenshot. I think problem is with joi. My regex seems to be working correctly

Comment: Do note that `t?` makes the `t` optional. Not sure if that is intended. The `{1,}` Can be written as just the `+`. Did you mean `^test\/(?:[A-Z \d]+\/)*$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/59bScR/1/)

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks it worked. If you will post it as answer I will mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex makes the s optional by using `s?` and will for example also match `tesing/` where `ing/` will be in the first capturing group because `([a-z0-9A-Z ]+\/)` will match until the forward slash.

If you only want to match and are not referring to the capturing group you can make it a non capturing group `(?:` and repeat that.

`^test\/(?:[A-Z \d]+\/)*$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/59bScR/1/)

That would match:

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `test\/` Match test/
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[A-Z \d]+\/` Character class which matches 1+ times an uppercase character, space or digit followed by a forward slash. Use `/i` flag to match case insensitive
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` Assert the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

All you have to is to move the check for a slash `'/`' to the front of the capturing group, like this:

```
/^test(\/[a-z0-9A-Z ]{1,})*/
```

Now it will match `'test'` and all subdirectories.